# Can I take break from tawba?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu alaikum brother,
I'm about to break one of my tawba. So Can I take a break from tawba once ? Instead of breaking it

Comment: How would you know that your tawba was accepted in first place? And who grants you to be alive to repent (again) later?

Comment: and if you are thinking of taking a break, then indeed your tawba was not sincere.
In one hadith, the Prophet ﷺ said, "Regret is tawba"
So if you truly regret something, you won't want to take a break and go back to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about the conditions for tawba/repentance, 1 sincere remorse, 2 determination to not do it ever again 3 I forgot, 4 trying to make things good if it affected someone else like returning a stolen item.

You can make tawba/repent from the same thing several times.

Ibn al-Qayim said you should make tawba again and again, and not making tawba is something to make tawba from.

Answer (score 0):

Take a break from tawbah if you can guarantee you will be alive during your break. Do you have enough confidence to meet Allah whilst openly happy to sin. If so, good luck.